# Internet Explorer Javascript Image Problem

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, image

I following the book "DOM Scripting" by Jeremy Keith and I have hit a wall in trying to get a small image gallery to render correctly in Internet Explorer 6/7.

I have 4 thumbnails which load in a placeholder when clicked using the following code:

```
function showPic(whichpic) {
    if (!document.getElementById("placeholder")) return true;
    var source = whichpic.getAttribute("href");
    var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");
    placeholder.setAttribute("src",source);
    if (!document.getElementById("description")) return false;
    var text = whichpic.getAttribute("title") ? whichpic.getAttribute("title") : "";
    var description = document.getElementById("description");
    if (description.firstChild.nodeType == 3) {
        description.firstChild.nodeValue = text;
    }
    return false;
}
```

My placeholder is inserted into the page using `createElement("img")`, however when I click a thumbnail the image is compressed to the size of the placeholder that it replaced.

```
function preparePlaceholder() {
    if(!document.createElement) return false;
    if(!document.createTextNode) return false;
    if(!document.getElementById) return false;
    if(!document.getElementById("imagegallery")) return false;
    var placeholder = document.createElement("img");
    placeholder.setAttribute("id","placeholder");
    placeholder.setAttribute("src","images/placeholder.gif");
    placeholder.setAttribute("alt","Gallery Placeholder");
    var description = document.createElement("p");
    description.setAttribute("id","description");
    var desctext = document.createTextNode("Choose an image");
    description.appendChild(desctext);
    var gallery = document.getElementById("imagegallery");
    insertAfter(placeholder,gallery);
    insertAfter(description,placeholder);
}
```

So the result as pictured below is a skewed image:

[image: In Chrome]
[image: In Explorer]

Live site here: http://anarchist.webuda.com/

Javascript here: http://pastebin.com/kaAhjdqk
HTML here: http://pastebin.com/Dm5p2Dj6
CSS here: http://pastebin.com/yiVPiQZe

Comment: Added: http://pastebin.com/yiVPiQZe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding to the `showPic` function the next 2 lines after `placeholder.setAttribute("src",source);`

```
placeholder.removeAttribute('width');
placeholder.removeAttribute('height');
```

Using **IE8 Developer Tools** (in Compatibility Mode) I could reproduce the problem and find that the `width` and `height` are being assigned automatically. So I tested with the debugger using the `removeAttribute` and the image grew to the proper size. But I don't really know if the place for those lines is exactly right, so let me know.